# android UI elements are not responsive

Tags: android, layout, responsiveness

I implemented a navigation drawer in my app. However, I bit later I noticed an issue - when I add some UI elements they are simply not responsive.

For instance, I cannot select an editText view and type text. Moreover, buttons do not invoke the onClick method (an onClickListener is attached). The navigation drawer is responsive and works fine. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeNTD.png) is how it looks like on an galaxy S3 I9300:

Here is the layout file of the myTasks activity (activity_my_tasks_topdrawer.xml):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                tools:context=".myTasks">


  <!--  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" -->


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                            android:id="@+id/drawer"
                                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="task content goes here"
        android:id="@+id/taskContent"/>
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="task date goes here"

        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_below="@+id/taskContent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Add"
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/taskContent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete"
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/updatButton"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/date"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/update"
        android:id="@+id/updatButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView">

    </ScrollView>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/submitButton">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
        <!--     -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >

            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                />




        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <com.radoslav.socialreminder.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:insetForeground="#4000"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
            <!--TODO: IMPORTANT might wanna remove this-->

            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
                android:name="com.radoslav.socialreminder.NavigationDrawerFragment"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"/>




        </com.radoslav.socialreminder.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the myTasks activity itself:

```
    package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;

public class myTasks extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_tasks_topdrawer);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);


        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setTxtUserEmail("rado9818@gmail.com");
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setTxtUsername("Radoslav Bonev");
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setProfilePic();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

   @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

NavigationDrawerFragment:

```
    package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "my_app_settings"; //TODO: change this to your file
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;

    private TextView txtUsername, txtUserEmail;
    private  ImageView image;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_google, container, false);

        //TODO: enter an actual email
        txtUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
        txtUserEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtUserEmail);
       // txtUsername.setText("Radoslav Bonev");
      //  txtUserEmail.setText("rado9818@gmail.com");

         image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);


        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readSharedSetting(getActivity(), PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public void setActionBarDrawerToggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle) {
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = actionBarDrawerToggle;
    }

    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        if(mFragmentContainerView.getParent() instanceof ScrimInsetsFrameLayout){
            mFragmentContainerView = (View) mFragmentContainerView.getParent();
        }
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(
                getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveSharedSetting(getActivity(), PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "true");
                }

                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);

        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
        List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Home", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("My tasks", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Group tasks", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("What do I miss?", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
        return items;
    }

    /**
     * Changes the icon of the drawer to back
     */
    public void showBackButton() {
        if (getActivity() instanceof ActionBarActivity) {
            ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Changes the icon of the drawer to menu
     */
    public void showDrawerButton() {
        if (getActivity() instanceof ActionBarActivity) {
            ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
        ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        selectItem(position);
    }

    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }

    public void setDrawerLayout(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    }

    public static void saveSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String settingValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(settingName, settingValue);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public static String readSharedSetting(Context ctx, String settingName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(settingName, defaultValue);
    }
    public void setTxtUsername(String username)
    {
        txtUsername.setText(username);
    }

    public void setTxtUserEmail(String email)
    {
        txtUserEmail.setText(email);
    }
    public void setProfilePic()
    {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        map.put("pic", R.drawable.profile);

        image.setImageResource(map.get("pic"));
    }
}    


    package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NavigationItem> mData;
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private int mTouchedPosition = -1;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(List<NavigationItem> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public NavigationDrawerCallbacks getNavigationDrawerCallbacks() {
        return mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(NavigationDrawerCallbacks navigationDrawerCallbacks) {
        mNavigationDrawerCallbacks = navigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row, viewGroup, false);
        final ViewHolder viewholder = new ViewHolder(v);
        viewholder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                                                       switch (event.getAction()) {
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                                               touchPosition(viewholder.getAdapterPosition());
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                                                               touchPosition(-1);
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                                               touchPosition(-1);
                                                               return false;
                                                       }
                                                       return true;
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                                       if (mNavigationDrawerCallbacks != null)
                                                           mNavigationDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(viewholder.getAdapterPosition());
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        return viewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());
        viewHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mData.get(i).getDrawable(), null, null, null);

        //TODO: selected menu position, change layout accordingly
        if (mSelectedPosition == i || mTouchedPosition == i) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_gray));
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    private void touchPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mTouchedPosition;
        mTouchedPosition = position;
        if (lastPosition >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        if (position >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void selectPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mSelectedPosition;
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        }
    }
}
```

NavigationDrawerAdapter:

```
    package com.radoslav.socialreminder;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;


public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NavigationItem> mData;
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private int mTouchedPosition = -1;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(List<NavigationItem> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public NavigationDrawerCallbacks getNavigationDrawerCallbacks() {
        return mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(NavigationDrawerCallbacks navigationDrawerCallbacks) {
        mNavigationDrawerCallbacks = navigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    @Override
    public NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row, viewGroup, false);
        final ViewHolder viewholder = new ViewHolder(v);
        viewholder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                                                       switch (event.getAction()) {
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                                               touchPosition(viewholder.getAdapterPosition());
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                                                               touchPosition(-1);
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                                               touchPosition(-1);
                                                               return false;
                                                       }
                                                       return true;
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        viewholder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                                       if (mNavigationDrawerCallbacks != null)
                                                           mNavigationDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(viewholder.getAdapterPosition());
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        return viewholder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());
        viewHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mData.get(i).getDrawable(), null, null, null);

        //TODO: selected menu position, change layout accordingly
        if (mSelectedPosition == i || mTouchedPosition == i) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_gray));
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    private void touchPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mTouchedPosition;
        mTouchedPosition = position;
        if (lastPosition >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        if (position >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    public void selectPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mSelectedPosition;
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        }
    }
}
```

If I have to provide something else, let me know.

Comment: I would add your MainActivity code. It would help to see if you're doing something wrong with your Java coding

Comment: Thanks! I have posted some more of the code where there might be something which causes the bug but I could not find anything.